# How to simplify $(u\times v)\cdot (v\times w)\times (w\times z)$ without brute force ($u,v,w,z\in \mathbb{R}^3$)?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to simplify $(u\times v)\cdot (v\times w)\times (w\times z)$ without brute force ($u,v,w,z\in \mathbb{R}^3$)? With only basic properties of the two products.

Answer (score 3):

Let $[a,b,c]$ be a shorthand for the triple product $a \cdot (b \times c)$.
Using the identities
$$a \times (b \times c) = (a\cdot c)b - (a\cdot b)c
\quad\text{ and }\quad
[a,b,c] = [b,c,a] = [c,a,b]
$$
we have
$$\require{cancel}(v \times w )\times(w \times z) = ((v \times w)\cdot z) w - \color{red}{\cancelto{\,0}{\color{gray}{((v \times w)\cdot w)}}}z = [v,w,z] w
$$
This leads to
$$\begin{align}[u\times v,v \times w,w \times z]
&= (u\times v)\cdot ([v,w,z]w)
= [v,w,z] (w\cdot (u \times v))\\
&= [v,w,z][w,u,v] = [u,v,w][v,w,z]
\end{align}
$$